# How do rewrites in NextJs for WebSocket?

Tags: next.js, ws

How to use http proxy for web socket with next js rewrites.

The `destination` does not start with `/`, `http://`, or `https://` for the flowing example.

```
{
  "source":"/websocket",
  "destination":"wss://some.domine.com/websocket"
}
```

How to solve it?